# Box filtering with skimage.transform.integral_image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-learn

I've faced with with the following problem. I try to make box filter 5x5 and want to calculate sum of the rectangle in a 4 points(A,B-1,C-1,D-1), where's B-1 is the upper left point and A is the lower right point. I try to figure out how should I calculate the first row and column, cause result smth like this:

```
[[  3   0 128 ... 128 128 128]
 [  0  40  40 ...   3   3   3]
 [  0  41  41 ...   4   4   4]
 ...
 [  0 116 114 ... 107 108 108]
 [128 116 112 ... 109 111 111]
 [  0 117 113 ... 110 112 113]]
```

skimage.transform.integrate() is not suitable cause it costs about 25 sec in loop and works correclty. My func integr() duration about 2s but problems with calculation of the first row and column. Thank you in advance for answers and thoughts

Below code is attached

```
import numpy as np

from skimage.io import imread, imsave, imshow
import skimage.transform

def integr(integ, start, end):
    C = (start[0], end[1])
    D = (end[0], start[1])
    sum = integ[start] + integ[end] - integ[C] - integ[D]
    return sum

img = imread('in.png')

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

out = np.zeros((296,396), np.uint8)

integ = skimage.transform.integral_image(img)

y = -1
for i in range(2, height-2, 1):
    y += 1
    x = -1
    for j in range(2, width-2, 1):
        x +=1
        start = (i-3, j-3)
        end = (i+2, j+2)
        out[y, x] = integr(integ, start, end)//25

ref = imread('ref.png')

res = out - ref
imshow(res)
print(out)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fast box filter, you won't get far with pure Python code. Use an optimized implementation like [scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html) or [cv2.boxFilter](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#boxfilter).